# Send and receive data from android to server

Tags: android, sql, http, post

I am currently coding an android app and I am a novice so it is very complicated for me to do the backend part.The app have to send some data informed in a form to a remote server and receive some data in a datalist too. I have been working on this with tutos and videos for 2 weeks and I did'nt succeed to do that. Is anyone able to send me simple codes (php, java) I can adapt easily to send and receive data?
I am currently working on WampServer and AndroidStudio.
I thank you for taking the time to read this and hope you have the solution to my problem!

Comment: `Is anyone able to send me simple codes` unfortunately, stack overflow isn't a free coding service, instead, post what you've tried and what you're struggling with

Comment: `Send and receive data from android to server` ? You mean `from your Android app`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your Android app won't be able to call your local server. To be able to communicate with a server, it has to be online. In fact, some solutions should be possible, but needing LOTS of boring configuration.
Anyway, once your server is online, have a look at Retrofit lib, which is perfect for web requests.

Comment: is this really worth writing as an answer, over just writing it as a comment ?

Comment: I thought Retrofit lib was the answer to their needs, and putting server online, the solution to potential issues...

Comment: `To be able to communicate with a server, it has to be online`. Nonsense. That can be a server on the Android device or on a local PC too.

Comment: Just read the rest of the answer: """In fact, some solutions should be possible, but needing LOTS of boring configuration."""

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way for you is create NodeJs + Express server, you can create 'localhost' server and test it, and when ready deploy to 'Heroku' for example.

Take a look on this page: [NodeJs + Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html)

Than to talk with this server, use Retrofit2 android library, [Here](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) is simple example.

Wish you luck.